# Sending dynamic data in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tell me please, there is a code for adding div elements that contain input with values. How to take data from these generated input and transfer to the database. What name should be at input, and what kind of query should be to write data rows in a database table. Thank you in advance.

```js
var p = document.getElementById("inputi");
var length = 1;

function add_input_from_select(select) {
  var new_input = document.createElement("input");
  new_input.name = "my_input";
  new_input.value = select.value;
  if(!new_input.value) return false;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<br>div элемент №' + length + '<br>';
  div.appendChild(new_input);
  p.appendChild(div);
  length++;
}

function add_input_old() {
  add_input_from_select(document.getElementById("selector"));
}
```

```html
<select id="selector" onchange="add_input_from_select(this)">
  <option value="">Выберите значение</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<form>
  <div id="inputi"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't know how you are connected to database from Javascript so I can't help doing connection part. To insert you should use https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp.

Comment: @karoluS I know how to add a row to the database. I don’t understand how the inputs should be called, which can be 10 or maybe 5. And the request should be $ _POST ['name_input'] which one is not clear if there are 10 of them.

Comment: You could write a javascript function which is binded to the onclick event and loops through all of the form controls in the DOM and POST them. Or, you could use javascript/jquery serialize

Comment: @JezD See, we added 5 input with our information. How do we transfer these 5 inputs to the database? We can have 10 input and maybe 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Index.html**

$Input = $YourData;

<form method="post" action="add_t_db.php">
<button type="submit" name="data" value=<?=$Input?> ><?php echo "Click to add     to DB" ; ?></button>  
</form>  


**add_t_db.php**


<?php

 $connect = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");  


if (!$connect) {
  echo 'Fail to connect to server';
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($connect,'essentialmode')) {
    echo 'databse not selected';

}

$Input = $_POST['data'];



$sql = "INSERT INTO table (colum1) VALUES ('$Input')";

if (!mysqli_query($connect,$sql)) {
    echo 'Not inserted';
}

else {
      echo 'inserted';
header("Location: URL");

}

?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code - why do you think that it solves the problem?